# What's the difference between `use base` and @ISA in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

I want to make a singleton class which extends DBI. should I be doing something like this:

```
use base 'Class::Singleton';
our @ISA = ('DBI');
```

or this:

```
our @ISA = ('Class::Singleton', 'DBI');
```

or something else?

Not really sure what the difference between 'use base' and 'isa' is.

Comment: Well, the base.pm documentation tells you the difference.

Answer (score 9):

The typical use of `@ISA` is

```
package Foo;

require Bar;
our @ISA = qw/Bar/;
```

The `base` and `parent` pragmas both load the requested class and modify `@ISA` to include it:

```
package Foo;

use base qw/Bar/;
```

If you want multiple inheritance, you can supply more than one module to `base` or `parent`:

```
package Foo;

use parent qw/Bar Baz/; #@ISA is now ("Bar", "Baz");
```

The `parent` pragma is new as of Perl 5.10.1, but it is installable from CPAN if you have an older version of Perl.  It was created because the `base` pragma had become difficult to maintain due to "cruft that had accumulated in it."  You should not see a difference in the basic use between the two.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the `parent` pragma instead of `base` as has been suggested in `perldoc base`.

Comment: Is 'parent' new in 5.10? It must be, as it's not in my 5.8 documentation.

Comment: I am not sure. However, quoting Chas's statement: "... The parent pragma is new as of Perl 5.10.1, but it is installable from CPAN if you have an older version of Perl. ..."

Answer (score 4):

from base's perldoc...

```
package Baz;

use base qw( Foo Bar );
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
package Baz;

BEGIN {
   require Foo;
   require Bar;
   push @ISA, qw(Foo Bar);
}
```

Personally, I use base.

Comment: The latest base.pm tells people to use parent, which is in 5.10.1. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit parent class then you would need to load it and modify @ISA. This both the steps are taken care of when you use Base. Base loads the module for you and modify @ISA accordingly. Otherwise you would need to modify @ISA and load the parent module on your own.

Both of the following are equivalent:

```
use base "Parent";
```

and

```
require Parent;
@ISA = ("Parent");
```