# Should I establish inheritance at compile-time rather than runtime, and if so why?

Tags: perl, inheritance

AFAIK inheritance in Perl is usually set up like this:

```
package Mule;
our @ISA = ("Horse", "Donkey");
```

Are there any examples where `use base` (or `use parent`) is better instead?

Comment: The `base` and `parent` modules allow you to establish ISA relationships at compile time. By contrast, modifying `@ISA` yourself happens at run time. In this light, one way to rephrase your question is like this: Is it generally advantageous to establish inheritance earlier (compile-time) rather than later, and if so why? Also see these related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378309/whats-the-difference-between-use-base-and-isa-in-perl/1379276 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876471/what-is-the-difference-between-parent-and-base-in-perl-5.

Comment: `BEGIN { @ISA = ... };` also happens at compile-time.

Comment: @FM Thanks for comment :-) I rephrased the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Establishing inheritance at compile time avoids a particularly hard to debug dependency loop, illustrated below.

```
# Child.pm
package Child;

our @ISA = qw(Mother);

use Foo;

# Mother.pm
package Mother;

sub wibble { 42 }

# Foo.pm
package Foo;

use Child;
Child->wibble;
```

If you "use Child" before "use Foo" then Foo will try to call `Child->wibble` before its established its inheritance on `Mother`.  If instead Child were to `use parent qw(Mother)` its inheritance would be established before it tried to load anything else.

I've been this sort of dependency loop in private, corporate code that tends to be a bit more intertwined than public code.  It sucks to debug, which is why I'd recommend always establishing inheritance at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

```
use base qw(Horse Donkey);
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
BEGIN {
    require Horse;
    require Donkey;
    push @ISA, qw(Horse Donkey);
}
```

It is tidier if you need to load the modules code as well as inheriting from them. BTW, there are issues with multiple inheritance, but thats a different question :)

**Edit:** Compile-time v. run-time advantages:

- You have the safety of the compile-time check with *use base* meaning your script won't even start if your base module is not present on the filesystem.
- If you want to decide to use a given module at run-time, then you can test and add the module to your parents:

  if (eval { require X }) {
      push @ISA, 'X';
  }

Comment: You can use use parent qw(base classes) or use base qw(base classes). parent is preferable over base because it has a lot less dark magic, but it isn't in core like base.

Comment: I'm too rusty in Perl to know more about 'parent'. Thanks @Leon +1

Comment: The `base` module will work when the parent class is in the same file. See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?base.

Comment: Leon: parent is in core. It just hasn't been for as long as base.

Comment: @FM: as will parent, only you have to be explicit about your intent

Answer (score 1):

Regarding compile-vs-run-time:

In Perl, modules (packages/namespaces) usually live in separate files. I.e. `Some::Module` would be find in Some/Module.pm. In this setup, the compile-vs-run-time difference won't matter much. The run-time of the module you load via `use()` will be before the compile-time of the calling code continues. Observer:

File `Some/Module.pm`:

```
package Some::Module;
BEGIN{ print "Some::Module - compile time\n" }
print "Some::Module - run time\n";
1;
```

File `test.pl`:

```
BEGIN{ print "Just started compiling the program.\n" }
use Some::Module;
BEGIN{ print "main - compile time\n" }
print "main - run time\n";
```

The output will be:

```
Just started compiling the program.
Some::Module - compile time
Some::Module - run time
main - compile time
main - run time
```

Therefore, an `our @ISA = qw(Base);` will be executed before the compilation of your main program continues after loading the module.

It is correct, however, that assigning to `@ISA` does not ensure that the base class has been loaded. That is why we have the `use base` and `use parent` pragmas. If you do not specifically need any features of `use base` (fields) nor require the longer backwards compatibility that it provides over `use parent`, I suggest you use the more light-weight `use parent`.